# Can't access Buefy component inside .beforeEach()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, buefy

I'm trying to access Toast component from Buefy to display an error everytime someone tries to access an auth only view:

```
// ...
import { Toast } from 'buefy/dist/components/toast'

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // ...
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (!(store.state.isAuth)) {
      Toast.open({
        message: "Not authorized"
      });
      next({
        path: '/login/',
      })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  } else {
    next()
  }
}
```

but `Toast` is undefined, I do have `Buefy` imported and `Vue.use(Buefy)` written.

How can I solve this problem and access Toast here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding, but should you not also be doing `Vue.use(Toast)`  since you are importing it by name?

Comment: I cannot use `Vue.use(Toast)`, it gives me `Cannot read property 'install' of undefined` since `Toast` is an undefined variable. The problem here is that I cannot import properly `Toast` component.

Comment: I have never used Buefy before, but a quick look at it seems to indicate you should be using the syntax for default export.  i.e  `import Toast from 'buefy/dist/components/toast'`  rather than a named import using curly braces  `{Toast}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue.

I got the $toast method from `Vue.prototype.$toast` since I loaded it with `Vue.use(Buefy)`.

Thanks for attention.

Comment: Ok just note in the future that there is a difference between how you import ES6 modules  if they have a named export or if they use default export.  The Buefy components definitely seem to be using default.  So you import without the braces and with really any name you want.  e.g  `import CoolToast from ....`   would work just as well.

Comment: P.S.  If you are ever in doubt look at the module you are importing.  https://github.com/buefy/buefy/blob/dev/src/components/toast/Toast.vue  You will see that it is using two default exports from other components, and it itself is using "export default."   A module with a named export will look like "export const Toast = 'something'"

Comment: I already tried to import directly, without curly braces, not successfully though, but I appreciate the advice, thank you.